# Is there a format string with sprintf that pads unless a float is whole?

Tags: c++, floating-point, format-specifiers

I am looking to use `sprintf` to format some float values but I can't seem to get the formatting right.
I have tried "`%1.6f`" as a format string but this isn't what I want.
The "`g`" specifier with significant digits also doesn't seem to help with other situations where I need the padding.

```
"1.6f"
Actual output: 1.000000
Expected Output: 1

"g"
Actual output: 1.1
Expected Output: 1.100000
```

Comment: To me (due to the way floating point number work on computers), `1` and `1.000` convey different information: `1` exactly `1` no question about it; `1.000` some number near `1` to 3dp but not exactly `1`.  Now add [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and the chance of getting an integer is quite small.  Best chance of getting what you want is to print to a buffer and inspect the contents, modify the buffer to be your required representation.

Comment: You want the `"%g"` format specifier...

Comment: @RichardCritten "chance of getting an integer is quite small" --> Not that small, 40+% of all `float` are whole numbers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  Assuming 32-bit integers and floats.  Then any float less than 1 or greater than 2^32 can not have an integer representation and I submit this is much larger than 40% of all floats.

Comment: @RichardCritten OP's question is about _whole numbers_: "... unless a float is whole?".  In that context [_integer_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) in not limited to 32-bit _int_, IAC, for common [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) 1,778,384,894 are whole numbers.  About 3% of `float` have 32-bit `int` values.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard specifier for that, but glibc supports custom specifiers. Here's an example implementation:

```
#include <printf.h>

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

int double_format(FILE *stream, const printf_info *info,
                  const void *const *args) {
  const double d = **reinterpret_cast<double const *const *>(args);

  if (std::trunc(d) == d) {
    return std::fprintf(stream, "%g", d);
  }

  int width = info[0].width;

  if (width == -1) width = 6;  // defaults to 6

  return std::fprintf(stream, "%.*f", width, d);
}

int double_format_arg_info(const struct printf_info *, size_t n, int *argtypes,
                           int *size) {
  if (n > 0) {
    argtypes[0] = PA_DOUBLE;
    size[0] = sizeof(double);
  }
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  register_printf_specifier('F', double_format, double_format_arg_info);
  std::printf("%4F && %4F\n", 1.0, 1.1);
}
```

Output is `1 && 1.1000`.

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bGjEvjPKE)

Comment: `but GCC and Clang support` It's not a feature of a compiler, but of a standard library. The GNU C library supports overriding printf specifier, unrelated to compiler.

Answer (score 2):

As there is no print specifier to meet OP's detailed need (`"%g"` is close), some test is needed.

To meet "unless a float is whole", test if the value is whole with `modf()` (or `modff()` in C for `float`). The function returns the fractional part.

```
// Illustrative code with printf vs sprintf
void mzkoops56_print(float x) {
  float ipart; 
  if (modf(x, &ipart) == 0.0) {
    printf("%.0f\n", x);
  } else {
    printf("%.6f\n", x);
  }
}
```

This will print non-whole values like 0.999996, 1.0000004 that are near a whole value with decimals.

```
mzkoops56_print(nextafterf(1.0,0));
mzkoops56_print(1.0);
mzkoops56_print(nextafterf(1.0,2));
mzkoops56_print(1.1f);

1.000000
1
1.000000
1.100000
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a format string with sprintf that pads unless a float is whole?

No, there is not. You have to write such functionality yourself. The algorithm basically would be:

- print with `%.6f` to temporary string
- check if that string ends with `.000000`

  - if so, remove `.000000`

Comment: If a non-whole value like 0.9999996, then this would result in `"1"` and not `"1.000000"`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that may or may not be what OP wants. Not exactly clear.